# In Spring Tool Suite 4, when creating a Run Configuration, the Project dropdown menu does not display any project. "No project selected"

Tags: spring, eclipse, sts

[Graphic for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZEG1.png)
In Spring Tool Suite's Run Configurations, there is an option for Spring Boot App. There is a dropdown menu meant to select the project, but currently there are not any options available. I seem to have a problem selecting a project, but I cannot find where to "select" a project if the dropdown menu does not display any options.

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but do you have any SpringBoot projects in your workspace?  In the package/project explorer, you would see "[boot]" next to the project name.  If you don't see any of those, that would be why there aren't any projects in the dropdown.

Comment: Hey David, not a silly question as I imported a SpringBoot project and it showed up as an available project. Thanks for the insight. My other projects do have the required SpringBoot dependencies, so I have to figure out why my projects are not recognized as such.